# Restrict cacheability of dynamic pages to CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I need to set some aspx dynamic pages to be cacheable by CloudFront.
I tried setting Cache-Control to public in the response header and it worked, but other layers are also caching my pages, such as my network proxy server (squid).
Is there any way to restrict the cacheability of my dynamic pages only to Amazon CloudFront?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a cache behavior for *.asxp or a more specific path, content/*.aspx and configure the minttl to be whatever value you wish.  Then you could set s-maxage for other proxies to respect.